# Instagram compresses logo profile picture

Tags: image-quality

I've tried exporting this logo as JPEG 640px with a size <1.6mb but it still looks compressed.[image: the logo in question]

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting in PNG, uncompressed and then uploading